# Create matrix from text file

Tags: matlab

I have a txt file with 4 column of real numbers like this

```
1 0 2 5
0 1 -6 2.5
-1 2 7 9
3 5 9 -2
```

ecc

Each column need to be a 200x200 matrix. What I should to is to read each single element of a the first column and put it into a matrix 200x200 matrix. As it is the file, it should not matter if the element in the second row (0 in the example) becomes the (1,2) element of the matrix or (2,1), since this matrix should be symmetric.

Can you help me?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your problem statement. You have 4 columns of real numbers, but now each column needs to be a `200 x 200` matrix.  Can you show us the expected output in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following approach, which in this example extracts the first matrix:

```
data = load(<path to txt file>)
N = size(data,1);
mat1 = zeros(sqrt(N),sqrt(N));
mat1(:) = data(:,1);
```

It is also possible to keep the 4 matrices in a cell, by using the following:

```
data = load(<path to file>)
N = size(data,1);
matCell = cell(size(data,2),1);
for ii=1:length(matCell)
   matCell{ii} = zeros(sqrt(N),sqrt(N));
   matCell{ii}(:) = data(:,ii);
end
```

In this case you can use matCell{1} to access the first 200x200 matrix.